# How to move a site developed using Zend Frameworks and Smarty templates

Tags: php, zend-framework

I have been asked to help move a website where the client and the developer have almost killed each other.

I have experience building PHP/mySQL sites, but not enough to handle this without some help.

Where to begin?

Is this even possible?

What do I have to get from the outgoing developers?

Any help would be appreciated.

---

Following some helpful comments below, I am adding the current site structure:

configs

cron

docs

framework

cache

classes

controllers
  fonts

init

lib

library

```
Admin stuff

Zend

  ControllerDispatcher

  Loader

  Forms..
```

modules

inc

templates_c

- non readable files

userfiles

the site files

views

images

js

media

style

templates

oops, that wasn't very helpful.  it's hard to type with one hand... (shoulder surgery)..
see if this is better..

Comment: From now on I would recommand you to take the Zend Framework "guided tour" by following the quick start (http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/learning.quickstart.intro.html) and then building a tutorial app to get the hang on Zend Framework (http://akrabat.com/zend-framework-tutorial/)

Comment: It seems maybe you should have someone do this who actually knows what they're doing?! Don't take this the wrong way but it looks like you might become the next guy to not get along with that customer... why doesn't a professional take care of the situation?

Comment: We will get someone professional at this Markus, so no insult taken. As I'll probably have the pleasure of managing this process, I just want to get my feet wet by asking some basic questions..

Answer (score 1):

If you just need to move the web app / web site, it's a pretty easy task as Zend Framework is "just" a php library

The default project structure goes as follow

```
Zend Web App
    Application
    Library
    Public
    Data
```

The `Application` folder is where most of the code goes, you have the 3 components of the `MVC`stack that goes there (Model-View-Controller). You also have the configuration for the Web app that goes there (in 'Application/configs/')

The `Library` folder contain code used in the App but that does not fit in the `MVC` stack. This is also one of the place where you could fit the `Zend`folder

The `Public` folder is the Web root of your application (you must set your Virtual Host to point to that folder).

The `Data` folder is not mandatory but its where you would have your translation resources, your logs, etc.

To link the Zend library to the Web App you have 2 choices : but the folder in the `Library` folder or edit the php.ini to set the include_path with the actual location of the `Library` on the web server disk (doesn't have to be in the server root, it can be anywhere).

If `Smarty`was used in the right way there should be a `Smarty` folder in the `Library` folder, so, it will move along the Web App

Comment: great. Thanks guys. That is really helpful. .... I have updated my original question to show the structure that we find. I really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

This is not a big problem at all. As long as the new server has a similar PHP environment. But honestly, the page will run on any good hosting. For a PHP app built on top of Zend Framework there are no problems whatsoever with moving. You just copy the app to the new place, let the vhost point to the public folder of your app and are good to go.

If the current library folder contains a folder `Zend` then this can either be a full copy of the framework or a Symlink to a full copy. Either way you just replicate that on the new hosting.

If the current library folder does NOT contain a `Zend` folder, then Zend Framework was on the PHP include path. So you have three options.

- include path
- real copy
- symlink

Comment: Thanks Markus. I'm only worried that we have been given all the site files and that we are not missing anything obvious..